# Xamarin.Forms.ListView vs Xamarin.FormsScrollView Performance

Tags: c#, performance, listview, xamarin, scrollview

**I need advice** as I have a complex **View** with an equally complex **ViewModel** (=BindingContext).

This View would be present up to 30 times, but most **often 5-8 times** in either a **ListView** or a **ScrollView**. (using it both iOS and Android)

**Facts:**

- View and its ViewModel need quite some time to initialize
- the View needs the ViewModel unconditionally to be useful
- View consists of a Grid (5rows, 7cols, mostly absolute/star-sized) + one nested StackLayout and a bigger ContentView consisting of another Grid (9rows, 8cols).
- Only one ContentView of all the Views has its IsVisible to true at a time
- the ContentView also holds a Grid that has up to 5 rows, each containing 3 children. The amount of rows is dynamically changing and relys on the ViewModel
- Most of the main views children are buttons, labels and input fields. also up to 10 images.

As I write this down, I already feel, that the View is wayyy to complex to use it as a ViewCell inside a ListView. I can't image smooth scrolling is possible this way and I haven't achieved it yet.

**ScrollView usage: (high initialization time, perfect scrolling)**

- 8 times this View inside a ScrollView leads to a initialization time of up to 5 seconds.
- Scrolling is perfectly smooth

**ListView usage: (moderate initialization time, horrible scrolling)**

- 8 times this View inside a ListView takes maximum 2 seconds to initialize (CachingStrategy RecycleElements)
- Scrolling is super bad, as the ViewModel has to compute too much on initialization.

What advice can you give me?
What would you do? ScrollView or ListView? Create the Views fully in native project?

I will have to work on the View and ViewModel and stick to performance tips (use LayoutOptions.Fill only, no nested Layouts, etc.)

But it will be very timeconsuming and I don't want to go down a road to notice that it is a deadend.

Comment: When you are talking initialization time, is that involving data bnding times, the actual view construction (Forms2Native build/rendering) or what is the `time suck`™ ? i.e. are you with compiled binding and OneWayToSource to within those views? Without specific code and profiling this is a very broad question....

Comment: Yeah, I know its pretty broad. What i mean by initialization time is the time the page needs to display the whole content, the listview/scrollview and make it interactable. Whats happening: Views are added, views are fully layed out and bindingcontext is fully configured (commands are attached, properties are bound, events are attached). The view construction is working kinda fast, but as soon as the viewmodel has to do work, it gets pretty slow. I tried making the viewmodel work when the bindingcontext changes vs. viewmodel do work in ctor, doesnt matter. both sucks

Comment: Can you share some of your code because it would make it a lot easier to help? Also, any intensive ViewModel work you should probably be doing on a background thread and show a spinner until it's finished.

Comment: But all this loading would happen as I scroll down the list. For ListView this would mean, any View thats not on screen has to be reloaded, showing a spinner anytime I scroll up/down. I might share some code soon. right now I dont have the time to sry